# PHP Class; Notice: Undefined property error

Tags: php, function, class, undefined

before I ask my question, I would like to say that I searched for this question, and none of the other answers helped...

Basically, in my class `DemoClass`, I have 4 functions, and all of them are "undefined properties"

My error:

> Notice: Undefined property: DemoClass::$function in /home/content/92/10270192/html/class.php on line 46

Note: line 46 is where i do $demoClass->function...

I have a typical class setup:

```
class DemoClass {
    public function __construct () {
        // stuff that works and gets called
    }
    public function testFunct () {
        // one that is an "undefined property"
    }
}
```

I access the class as normal:

```
$testClass = new DemoClass();
var_dump(testClass->testFunct); // this is what is on line 46
// ^^^ This also gives me NULL, because its undefined (? i guess...)
```

I've never had this problem before, any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Brackets are required when calling a function. Change it to `$testClass->testFunct()` instead.

Comment: My apologizes - that is a typo in the question, I have it correct in my implementation...

Comment: Should be `$testClass` (dollar-sign prefix)

Answer (score 2):

`$testClass->testFunct` references a variable `testFunct` in the class.  You need to use `$testClass->testFunct()` to reference a function in the class.

Comment: Am I that dumb?  Wait... yes I am - thanks!  I need some sleep ;)

Comment: Get to bed before you break any more of your code, then come back refreshed! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
var_dump(testClass->testFunct())
```

A function always needs the parentheses as else (as you can see) you can't tell the difference between a function and a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike for instance JavaScript, PHP is not handling class methods as regular properties.

When you use `$testClass->testFunct`, PHP looks for a *property* named `testFunct` and finds none.

Methods can be referenced through class name, `DemoClass::testFunct` in your case.

Comment: Note: accessing methods via class name, like `DemoClass::testFunct` requires the method to be `static`.

Comment: Well technically you can access it, but trying to invoke it will end up in tears (which makes this access of very limited use indeed).